# Create a separate predicate

Tags: lambda, java-8, predicate

I have a following filter in my list. I need people living in the specified timeframe where validTo in both lists are Optional. As you can see, it's little bit complicated and since there other filters I need to make it simple by moving the predicate to a variable.

```
people.stream()
            .filter(person -> peopleTime.stream().anyMatch(time ->
                    (!person.getValidTo().isPresent() || time.getValidFrom().isBefore(person.getValidTo().get()) || time.getValidFrom().isEqual(person.getValidTo().get()))
                            && (!time.getValidTo().isPresent() || time.getValidTo().get().isAfter(person.getValidFrom()) || time.getValidTo().get().isEqual(person.getValidFrom()))))
```

I tried to create some BiPredicate and use it but anyMatch expects single predicate. Person class extends Time class.

Any help, please?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, what are you trying to do ? To simplify your `Predicate<Time>` to a single method ? What is blocking you ?

Comment: There are two parameters - Person and Time. It's not single Predicate, it's rather BiPredicate.

Comment: Yes, but those two parameters don't have the same scope. You can perfectly create a `Predicate<Time>` encapsulating a person.

Comment: How exactly encapsulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm understanding, you basically have :

```
public abstract static class MyDate {
    public abstract boolean isBefore(MyDate other);
    public abstract boolean isAfter(MyDate other);
    public abstract boolean isEqual(MyDate other);
}
public static abstract class Time {
    public abstract Optional<MyDate> getValidTo();
    public abstract Optional<MyDate> getValidFrom();
}

public static abstract class Person extends Time {
}
```

(Well, I'm leaving the implementation for now).

If you create the following class :

```
public static class TimePersonPredicate implements Predicate<Time> {

    private final Person person;
    public TimePersonPredicate(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean test(Time time) {
        return (!person.getValidTo().isPresent() || time.getValidFrom().get().isBefore(person.getValidTo().get()) || time.getValidFrom().get().isEqual(person.getValidTo().get()))
                && (!time.getValidTo().isPresent() || time.getValidTo().get().isAfter(person.getValidFrom().get()) || time.getValidTo().get().isEqual(person.getValidFrom().get()));
    }

}
```

You can shorten your filter line like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Time> peopleTime = new ArrayList<>();
    people.stream()
        .filter(person -> peopleTime.stream().anyMatch(new TimePersonPredicate(person) ))...
}
```

Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Thanks. Finally I used a static  method which is similar:
.filter(person -> peopleTIme.stream().anyMatch(time -> intersection(person, time)))